# Django DRF serializer method field on many to many running 2n queries

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, many-to-many, django-orm

I'm using **Django 2.2** and **Django REST Framework**.

I have the following model structure

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  name = models.ChartField(max_length=200)

class Tag(models.Model):
  name = models.ChartField(max_length=50, unique=True)

class MyModelRelation(models.Model):
  obj = models.ForeignKey(MyModel, related_name='relation')
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

  def tag_list(self):
     return self.tags.all().values_list('name', flat=True).distinct()
```

I want to get the tags list with the `MyModel` instance and for that, the serializer is

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  tags_list = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

  def get_tags_list(self, obj):
     return obj.relation.tag_list()

  class Meta:
    fields = [
      'name',
      'tags_list'
    ]
```

and the view is

```
class ObjListView(ListAPIView):
  serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
  
  def get_queryset(self):
    return super().get_queryset().select_related('relation').prefetch_related('relation__tags')
```

But to get 58 records, it is running almost 109 queries.

[image]

The `` my_app_mymodel`, `my_app_mymodelrelation_tags `` is repeated multiple times

Comment: This is due to the `tag_list` method in the model class. It is called for each model instance and most likely twice. Note thay such queries are run as new DB queries and so your select_related or prefetch_related doesn't help. You can try to annoate the `tag_list` instead of using the method

Comment: I used the same logic inside the serializer method field and still same number of queries. Can you give an example with annotate?

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

This is how I suggest you solve the problem. Instead of extracting the name in the DB level, you can do it in the serializer level. It will make things way easier and faster. First, remove the `tag_list` method from the model class. First add the annotation to your views:
from django.db.models import F

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return super().get_queryset().annotate(tags_list=F('relation__tags')).select_related('relation')
```

Then in your serializers

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  tags_list = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, slug_field='name', read_only=True)
...
```

Comment: It is giving `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: I haven't run this code, so I am not aware of the errors. Can you atleast try to find out where the type error is coming from? The stack trace should show you

Comment: I just saw that I omitted a bracket in the annotate. I don't know if that's what caused the type error but you can try again. If you it gives an error, please try to see where it is coming from and let me know as I can't run the code myself

Comment: bracket is not the problem. After debugging inside the `Serializer` library, the above field is converted to `ManyRelatedField(child_relation=SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='name'), read_only=True)` and the attribute is an integer, instead of the iteratable. The `ManyRelatedField.to_representation()` expects an iteratable but it is getting an integer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220726/discussion-between-anuj-tbe-and-ken4scholars).

Comment: It seems the issue with the `annotate`. It is annotating only single instance of tag instead of the list.